# Selenium not clicking element

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following checkbox element:

```
<input checked="checked" class="iceSelBoolChkbx" 
id="mainContentId:newSerchCheckBox" name="mainContentId:newSerchCheckBox" 
onblur="setFocus('');" 
onclick="var form=formOf(this);iceSubmitPartial(form, this, event);" 
onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" 
onkeypress="var form = formOf(this);
Ice.util.radioCheckboxEnter(form,this,event);" 
type="checkbox">
```

I currently am locating the element and attempting to click it using

```
check_box = driver.find_element_by_id('mainContentId:newSerchCheckBox')
check_box.click()
```

When I run the code it runs without any errors but on the site the checkbox is still unchecked. What could be causing this and is their an alternative way to check the box?

Comment: Have you tried selecting by xpath, just to test?

Comment: Can you provide the url or the HTML you're trying to access? Even though ID's should be unique and only applied to a single element, that might not be the case and you might be clicking the wrong element.

Comment: I had a very similar problem and resolved it using jquery. Do you know if jquery is on the page?

Comment: @SuperStew tried xpath, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing click with mousedown, I don't know what the underlying difference is but it resolved the issue I was having with click().

```
driver.execute_script('$("#mainContentId:newSerchCheckBox").trigger("mousedown")')
```

Let me know if you're thrown an error and we can re-write it in pure Javascript rather than relying on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think your checkbox is already selected if you see the input tag `checked="checked"`.So you need to check first whether selected or not.If selected do not click.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("mainContentId:newSerchCheckBox")
if element.is_selected():
    print('Check box is already selected')
else:
    element.click()
```

Comment: i think it's better to use `pyautogui` to click it,because some sites can detect this move hence(ban) i.e `x,y=element.location()`